# Activation of Gmail for secondary domain fails though MX records are added in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: mx-record, gmail, activation

Gmail for the main domain is activated
I added a secondary domain. In https://admin.google.com/ the status is: varified + Gmail activation failed.
When I start activation on the last step I see that MX records are not found:
Your MX records didn't match. You'll need to delete and add the missing records below.
Though I added the same MX records, as for the main domain in console.cloud.google.com:
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
and so on

What might be the problem? Did I miss some steps?
Thank you

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: How this question is related to Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: It is connected to Google Cloud Platform, because Google.Admin support sent me there and there is no support for Google Cloud Platform

Comment: Our registrar is GoDaddy. Correct NS records are added there and are not propagating in all locations (only in one). Sorry if I write something incorrectly - I'm completely new to this theme. Domain name - tomiai.us